# jq reduce (or map?) to transform to object containing {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2" }

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file in the following format:

```
{
    "foo": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "hello"
    },
    "bar": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "goodbye"
    }
}
```

I want to transform it to:

```
{
"foo": "hello",
"bar": "goodbye"
}
```

Best I have got to:

```
cat file.json | jq 'to_entries[] | reduce . as $item ({}; reduce . as $value ({}; $item.key + ":" + $item.value.value))'
```

which gives:

```
"foo:hello"
"bar:goodbye"
```

close, but still a long way to go.

All assistance appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`to_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) makes the problem much more difficult than it needs to be.

The problem can instead be solved in just one simple operation.

Since you want to update the value of each key, it makes sense to use [`map_values`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)), which is meant for this purpose:

```
jq 'map_values(.value)' file.json
```

Output:

```
{
  "foo": "hello",
  "bar": "goodbye"
}
```

See the documentation for `map_values` [here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#map(x),map_values(x)).